# find unique column as row index in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

As I know there is no primary key in Google BigQuery, so what is the best why to find unique column to use as row index?

I can think of using:

```
SELECT count(*) as totalnumber, count(distinct columnname) as uniquecolumn from `db`
```

But is there any better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HASH functions for this  - for example [FARM_FINGERPRINT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions#farm_fingerprint)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(t)) AS uniquecolumn 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

FARM_FINGERPRINT() computes the fingerprint of the STRING or BYTES input using the Fingerprint64 function from the open-source FarmHash library. The output of this function for a particular input will **never change**, so you can use it as a sort of row index

Comment: What happens if there is duplicated row?

Comment: you will get duplicate value as FARM_FINGERPRINT() always computes same output for same value - so you might want to address duplicates in your data first

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GENERATE_UUID` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/uuid_functions):

```
SELECT *, GENERATE_UUID() AS uniquecolumn
FROM `dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I use this UUID as row index for inner join nested query? In another word, I will have the same result every time I run GENERATE_UUID() against the same row.

Comment: You will not--you would need to associate a specific UUID with each row by writing the result of this query to a new table. If the goal is to have row IDs without needing to persist them to a table, then see Mikhail's answer.